# Optimized GPU to CPU data transfer

Tags: performance, opengl, graphics

I'm a bit out of my depth here (best way to be me thinks), but I am poking around looking for an optimization that could reduce GPU to CPU data transfer for my application.

I have an application that performs some modifications to vertex data in the GPU. Occasionally the CPU has to read back parts of the modified vertex data and then compute some parameters which then get passed back into the GPU shader via uniforms, forming a loop.

It takes too long to transfer all the vertex data back to the CPU and then sift through it on the CPU (millions of points), and so I have a "hack" in place to reduce the workload to usable, although not optimal.

What I do:

1. CPU: read image
2. CPU: generate 1 vertex per pixel, Z based on colour information/filter etc
3. CPU: transfer all vertex data to GPU
4. GPU: transform feedback used to update GL_POINT vertex coords in realtime based on some uniform parameters set from the CPU.

When I wish to read only a rectangular "section", I use glMapBufferRange to map the entire rows that comprise the desired rect (bad diagram alert):

[image]

This is supposed to represent the image/set of vertices in the GPU. My "hack" involves having to read all the blue and red vertices. This is because I can only specify 1 continuous range of data to read back.

Does anyone know a clever way to efficiently get at the red, without the blue? (without having to issue a series of glMapBufferRange calls)

EDIT-

The use case is that I render the image into a 3D world as GLPoints, coloured and offset in the Z by an amount based on the colour info (sized etc according to distance). Then the user can modify the vertex Z data with a mouse cursor brush. The logic behind some of the brush application code needs to know the Z's of the area under the mouse (brush circle), eg. min/max/average etc so that the CPU can control the shaders modification of data by setting a series of uniforms that feed into the shader. So for example the user can say, I want all points under the cursor to set to the average value. This could all probably be done entirely in the GPU, but the idea is that once I get the CPU-GPU "loop" (optimised as far as I can reasonably do), I can then expand out the min/max/avg stuff to do interesting things on the CPU that would be cumbersome (probably) to do entirely on the GPU.

Cheers!
Laythe

Comment: Your question makes an assumption: that `glMapBufferRange` is *copying* data to the CPU. While that is certainly a possible implementation of mapping, generally speaking, the purpose of mapping is to access the GPU-accessible memory directly. So it doesn't really matter how large a range you map; what matters is how much synchronization the GPU has to do to make that data visible.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas Hi Nicol, thanks for the reply. I'm just trying to get a handle on the "theory" really as from what i have so far learnt, I cannot rely on something working well (or working at all) solely on the basis of it working on my dev machine. I have an latop Intel Iris integrated card. What I see is *huge* perf improvements by simply cutting out the white areas in my diagram (not reading those rows). It could just be an artifact of my graphics driver implementation, but without the theory its difficult for me to judge, cheers

Comment: If you know where your red part is located, maybe you only need one MapBufferRange if you know the precise offset.

Comment: @Draykoon D I know the precise location of everything and therefore offsets, however the problem is that the 2D image/vertices is actually a 1D array in the GPU, and because I want the red *only*, this means I want access to multiple continuous "ranges" of vertex data within the GPU, without having to actually issue several (1 per row for the red) glMapBufferRange calls. Ie it would be nice to have a facility to ask the GPU once for all the ranges, rather than ask it once per row, which would involve a CPU-GPU interaction per row (of the red).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get any data from the GPU to the CPU you need to map the GPU memory in any case, which means the OpenGL application will have to use something like `mmap` under the hood. I have checked the implementation of that for both x86 and ARM, and it looks like it is page-aligned, so you cannot map less than 1 contiguous page of GPU memory at any given time, so even if you could request to map just the red areas, you quite likely would also get the blue ones as well (depending on your page and pixel data sizes).

**Solution 1**
Just use glReadPixels, as this allows you to select a window of the framebuffer. I assume a GPU vendor like Intel would optimize the driver, so it would map as few pages as possible, however this is not guaranteed, and in some cases you may need to map 2 pages just for 2 pixels.

**Solution 2**
Create a compute shader or use several glCopyBufferSubData calls to copy your region of interest into a contiguous buffer in GPU memory. If you know the height and width you want, you can then un-mangle and get a 2D buffer back on the CPU side.

Which of the above solutions works better depends on your hardware and driver implementation. If GPU->CPU is the bottleneck and GPU->GPU is fast, then the second solution may work well, however you would have to experiment.

**Solution 3**
As suggested in the comments, do everything on the GPU. This heavily depends on whether the work is parallelize-able well, but if the copying of memory is too slow for you, then you don't have much other choice.

Comment: Hi Ed, Thanks for your answer. I suspected that what I was wanting was not directly available. When you say page of GPU mem, how big are we talking - I did a google but was overwhelmed with memory system details it was hard to translate what I was looking at into an answer for that... Cheers!

Comment: Hi Laythe, I think a common size would be 4KB, however it depends on the hardware. I mainly work with embedded GPUs, but I think the aforementioned size is a good minimum to assume in general nowadays. That is why I was saying that it can be almost a whole row of pixels if your pixel data size was 4 bytes and your width was 1080. Hope this helps! Do update me on what solution worked for you in the end.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you are asking because you can not do all work at shaders, right?

If you render to a Frame Buffer Object, then bind it as GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, you can read a block of it by `glReadPixels`.

Comment: Yes it may be possible, however there is a whole bunch of logic that sits in that loop, so converting it to shaders may be problematic but will be something I definitely look into. Regarding the glReadPixels, would I not still have the same problem? - Ie I would have to read back the blue and the red to get the red (in my diagram above).

Comment: @Laythe you can use `glReadPixels` directly ... PS Not sure which Intel HD gfx you got but all the older ones I tested on Can not render to **FBO** and or to textures due to bad drivers so glReadPixels is the only way that works reliably on those.

Comment: @Spektre I'm not sure how this would help my situation because my problem is that the 2D image/vertices is actually a 1D array in the GPU, and because I want the red only, this means I want access to multiple continuous "ranges" of vertex data within the GPU, without having to actually issue several (1 per row for the red) glMapBufferRange calls. Ie it would be nice to have a facility to ask the GPU once for all the ranges, rather than ask it once per row, which would involve a CPU-GPU interaction per row (of the red)